# How to verify FreeBSD iso download?

Tags: freebsd, system-installation, gpg

I've just downloaded a FreeBSD 11.0 iso file from the FreeBSD website. I've also obtained the signed SHA512 and SHA256 checksum files. The website says that the checksum files are PGP-signed. How do I verify the integrity of the downloaded iso? Where do I get the public key to verify the signature in the checksum files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are in a Linux / Unix-like system,

```
sha256sum /path/to/freebsd.iso
sha512sum /path/to/freebsd.iso
```

will print the checksums.

The public PGP key is likely [one of these](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/articles/pgpkeys/).

Comment: Do you know which key exactly? I downloaded the complete keyring. The download was successfully verified, but now I have hundreds(?) of keys I'll not be using again.

Comment: It turns out this piece of information is really hard to find in the internet. I did some research but could not find it. This should be explicitly documented somewhere. I think you could infer it from your local keyring (a good topic for another question) and then, if you want, send a suggestion to FreeBSD developers to document it explicitly in the Download page.